# Convert a query from SQL to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am unable to convert a query in from sql to elasticsearch.

Sql query to convert : -

> select tb1.* from table tb1 where tb1.coloumn1 in
>   ("value1","value2","value3") and  tb1.coloumn2 = "value4" and
>   tb2.cloumn3 = "value5";
>
> curl 'http://***.***.**.**:9200/index1/document/_search?pretty' -d
>   '{"query": { "constant_score" : {            "filter" : {
>   "terms" : { "product" : ["Sudaderas","Bicicletas"]}            }
>   }}}'

---------------Error--

> {   "took" : 8,   "timed_out" : false,   "_shards" : {
>       "total" : 5,
>       "successful" : 5,
>       "failed" : 0   },   "hits" : {
>       "total" : 0,
>       "max_score" : null,
>       "hits" : [ ]   } }

Thanks,Dip

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work ?

Comment: Have tried terms query. But it is not working. I have added a curl command.

Comment: Just downvoted the question no answer ??? ... then Y to downvote ??

Comment: Take it easy man, the downvote is because this question provided minimal information.

Comment: Can you a sample of documents your expecting to return ?

Comment: figured it out. :) ... Had to use bool query with must and should with terms query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql query converted to elasticsearch : -

**SQl query** : -

> select tb1.* from table tb1 where tb1.coloumn1 in
>   ("value1","value2","value3") and tb1.coloumn2 = "value4" and
>   tb2.cloumn3 = "value5";

**Elasticsearch query** : -

> {   "bool" : {
>       "must" : {
>         "terms" : {
>           "column1" : [ "tops","blusas" ]
>         }
>       },
>       "should" : [ {
>         "match" : {
>           "column2" : {
>             "query" : "Blusas",
>             "type" : "boolean"
>           }
>         }
>       }, {
>         "match" : {
>           "column3" : {
>             "query" : "Blusas",
>             "type" : "boolean"
>           }
>         }
>       } ]   } }

There are a lot of changes that had to be made to make this work with terms query. But will list Some : -

1. Terms query only searches on lowercase. As our default analyzer is set that way.
2. It does not really matter if the field is analyzed or not_analyzed. Somewhere while figuring out this terms query thingy I found that field should not be analyzed. That was also due to the default analyzer.

Make sure when you use terms/ term query then use lowercase.

3. **Not completely Clear :  -**  Terms query doesnot work when the query has spaces. I am trying to fix this issue. But the current problem has been fixed.

**Spring Elasticsearch Java** Same query implementation : -

> SearchQuery searchQuery1 = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
>                 .withQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("column1",
>   column1List))
>                         .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("column2", data)).should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("coloumn3", data)))
>                 .build();
>
> List table1List = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery1,
>                       table.class);

The column1List has all elements as single word and is converted to lowercase while inserting it into an array .

Hope this helps someone in future.

Let me know if there is a better way of doing this thing.

Thanks